# Updating sci-hub manuscript version

Tags: journals, sci-hub

The manuscripts version made online in journals are often updated. For example, from the "Accepted" to "Final" version.

Many times the version retrieved by sci-hub is outdated, is there any way to force sci-hub to get the last published version?

Comment: Why ask us? Ask Sci-Hub....

Comment: @SolarMike for the same reasons many ask about Scopus, PubMed, Google Scholar, etc, in this site.

Comment: @Orion so common sense would suggest directly asking the source for updates and corrections, neither of which we have control of on this site...

Comment: @SolarMike The OP is asking about a feature academics already know and use.

Comment: @Orion and probably clearly explained in the help files...

Comment: @user1420303 sorry to say but you don't really understand the purpose of scihub or how it works. It's not a service where you can make requests, there's nobody uploading papers, it's all automated (for the most part).

Comment: @HermanToothrot, Clearly I was aware of the automation, notice the word "force" in the question.  Clearly I do not know in detail how Scihub works, that is why I asked in this site. Often, people asking questions are aware that they do not know everything surrounding about what they are asking about, so your comments in this respect have not added value. I found them violent and unconstructive, please keep them for you. Have a good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reload button does not show up anymore.

Also, this problem is likely related to storage of pre-print versions in sci-hub databases. From what I know, sci-hub only uses credentials on the first request for a paper. At that moment, it also saves a copy of the pdf and that copy is what is given as a result on subsequent requests.

So, I guess a solution to this problem has to involve updates to sci-hub's database.

Comment: The second part of your answer is correct, but the reload button is not to update the paper to a newer verrsion.

Answer (score 2):

You can request a newer version of an article using the "reload" button.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this? I thought this would just download the same file again.

Comment: I didn't use it recently (this year) but in the past it worked as I remember. Now it seems to open an empty page.

Comment: I confirm that this is not working at the moment

Comment: @Orion, no that's not how the 'reload' button works, it just reloads the paper...

Comment: @HermanToothrot [Many people used this button to obtain a newer version](https://www.google.com/search?q=sci-hub%20reload%20new%20version%20site:www.reddit.com). Anyway, thanks for the downvote ;)

Comment: @Orion that's not how it works, look at the code on github if you don't believe me :-)

Comment: @HermanToothrot Could you please share the link to the code on GitHub here?

Comment: @Orion https://github.com/freescience/Sci-Hub-2011

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding Sci-hub works by granting access to papers through the official system [credentials "donated"](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/04/whos-downloading-pirated-papers-everyone) by users around the world.

Therefore, I'd think the root of this artefact relies on the user's access credential settings or terms as used for those specific papers at the time the mirror database you're using was last updated. [I know it sounds unclear, but read carefully and I am sure you'll get my meaning.] 
Given this is probably automated by Sci-hub internal system, and there are likely very few active programmers behind the interface, I don't think asking them directly would return any answers.

My best bet is that you try out accessing the paper you want through a [different database mirror](https://sci-hub.now.sh) which might be more up to date.

Good luck!

Comment: "official system" is really not the word I would use. And it doesn't work as you described, I don't think you understand how sci-hub works...